# How to change the date datatype in text format to datetime format

Tags: mysql

I am importing a csv file to MySQL workbench. When importing the table, the date column is in text format.

```
date_added 
2018-04-07
```

How can I change the date_added to datetime format without including the Time?

I know str_to_date function lets us convert to text format to DateTime, 
Provided, the date_added is in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

How can I achieve this without adding the time component?

Comment: Is the date really 97th April, 2018?

Comment: ha ha! Sorry. Just edited

Comment: mysql provides date type

Comment: If your table has a column with datatime datatype, just import 2018-04-07 and see if mysql auto-converts it to timestamp with you having to do anything else

Comment: It does not pick up any data after import. Although it gives us an option to choose the datatype as datetime for that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert the column format, you can do that with an `ALTER TABLE` command. Since your value is already in the MySQL date format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) no conversion is necessary. If you want the column to be a `DATE`, just use

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY d DATE
```

Or if you want `DATETIME` format, use

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY d DATETIME
```

In the latter case MySQL will automatically add `00:00:00` as the time to the value.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4715be568d395cbee800f1d05f0bd268)